# HerokuからAWSに移行する難易度

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, heroku

始めはHerokuでスタートして、成功したサービスのみAWSに移行していこうと考えているのですが、HerokuからAWSに移行するのは難しい作業なのでしょうか。

ちなみにWEBサービスは基本的なCRUDのサイトです。dbはどちらともpostgresqlを使う予定です。AWSではElasticBeanstalkを使う予定です。

Comment: 「難しい作業なのでしょうか」という問いだと人によって意見が異なるので、あまり適切な質問ではありません。「heroku aws 移行」や「migrate from heroku to aws」のようなキーワードで検索するといろいろと情報が集まるので、まずそれらをチェックして実際に試してみる、もしくは理解できなかった点に質問をフォーカスする、といったアクションを取ってみてください。

Answer (score 1):

先月、HerokuからAWSへの移行を行いました。「難しい作業なのでしょうか」の質問ですので、まったくの主観による回答になりますが、難しかったです。
EC2の立ち上げやデータベース設定まではAWSの基本に沿って行えばOKでしたが、その後でいろいろツマりました。問題が起きた箇所を特定してご質問されることをオススメします。